# remove all white spaces in media query navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I created a media query for phones with 414px width size and less or iPhone 6 plus "portrait". I am trying to make a drop down menu and I got everything to work, its just the navigation bar is not moving. I gave it "margin:0,padding:0" left and right and all the above and nothing. If you open up my website in a "inspect element" and select "iPhone 6plus" version, you can see my navigation bar has a lot of white spaces and needs to be aligned left and all white margins and paddings cleared. Can someone please show me how I can bring it back to the top-left or atlas remove all the white spaces in my media query for "iphone 6plus " or screen sizes smaller than 414. My html will be uploaded here and the rest will be in a code pen.

Demo: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpwbJp

Screen shot
https://i.gyazo.com/605e7bb39ef78197fa24e2dcdab03427.png

Html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 

             <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="magicstyle.css">

        </head>     
        <body>
            <!-- Section for Jobs Popup -->
            <div id="top-bar">
                  <a class="burger-nav"></a>
                    <ul id="nav-menu" class="testAgain">
                    <li id="job" class="testAgain">Job</li>
                    <li id="contact" class="testAgain">Contact</li>
                    <li id="press" class="testAgain">Press</li>
                    <li id="legal" class="testAgain">Legal</li>
                    <li id="support" class="testAgain">Support</li>


                </ul>
                    <!--<div id="nav-menu">
                    <span id="job">Jobs</span>
                    <span id="contact">Contact</span>
                    <span id="press">Press</span>
                    <span id="legal">Legal</span>
                    <span id="support">Support</span>

                    </div> -->


                </div>
                 <div id="job-popup">
            <div class="x-div1"><img class="x-icon1" id="fadeX1" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png" alt="Text alternative when image is not available"></div>
            <div id="job-content">

                <h1 id="jobWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Section for Contact Popup -->
            <div id="contact-popup">
            <div class="x-div2"><img class="x-icon2" id="fadeX2" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="contact-content">

                <h1 id="contactWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>

            <!-- Section for Press Popu -->
             <div id="press-popup">
            <div class="x-div3"><img class="x-icon3" id="fadeX3" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="press-content">

                <h1 id="pressWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="legal-popup">
            <div class="x-div4"><img class="x-icon4" id="fadeX4" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="legal-content">

                <h1 id="legalWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="support-popup">
            <div class="x-div5"><img class="x-icon5" id="fadeX5" src="Pictures/web%20x%20icon%20white.png"></div>
            <div id="support-content">

                <h1 id="supportWords"></h1>

                </div>

            </div>




            <div id="container">


                <div id="name-div">
                <h1 id="name">Open Touch</h1>
                </div>
                <ul class="bubbles">

            <li id="firstCircle"></li>
            <li id="secondCircle"></li>
            <li id="thirdCircle"></li>
            <li id="fourthCircle"></li>
            <li id="fifthCircle"></li>
            <li id="sixthCircle"></li>



            </ul>



            </div>


        </body>





</html>
```

Any help at this point is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you wanting to make it so the list items disappear at that width? I'm confused a little.

Comment: I got an answer 1 minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your CSS layout. The order of your @media queries matter.

So here your

```
@media screen and (max-width:770px)
```

has precedence over

```
@media screen and (max-width: 414px)
```

simply because it came last in the code, and in this case `max-width: 414` also follows the rules of `max-width 770px` because anything under 414px is also under 770px.

so simply change the order of the code in the CSS file.

After this, as for the margins on the id tag `#nav-menu` put `margin: 0;`

Hope this Helps :)

Comment: WOw i love this website :D THank you